# Simple problem or conditions missing?!

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

When $f(x)$ is a differentiable function satisfying
$$x \cdot f(x) = x^2 + \int_0^x (x-t)f'(t) \,\mathrm dt $$
find $f(1)$.

---

Someone posted this problem on FB. I am copying its wording literally - see [here $(1)$](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=4084557118331855&set=gm.3069533923268230) and [here $(2)$](https://www.facebook.com/groups/2692404370981189/permalink/3069533923268230/).

Four or five people "solved it" (just using some symbolic manipulations without too much thought, I think) and so they say it's easy. They get that $f(1)=2$ and even that $f(x) = 2x$. But I think they are making some assumptions that are not given here.

I think they all assume $f'(x)$ is continuous and based on that they apply the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). Am I correct?

It is not even clear what is the domain of $f$ but let's say it's all real numbers. The best I can conclude from what is given in this problem is that $xf'(x) = 2x$. But again, I think I used that $f'(x)$ is continuous to get there and that is not even given. Also I think I got that $f(0) = 0$.

But I can't say anything about $f'(0)$, I can't claim it even exists.
And they just say $f(x)=2x$ for each $x$, which seems too strong conclusion to me.

Is this problem really simple? Or is it deeper and does it need some additional conditions/assumptions to be solved properly i.e. to have an unambiguous/unique answer?

Comment: I agree with you. Actually, I believe that the problem is, as you say, not even well defined: since there is no continuity hypothesis on $f'$ and there is no integrability hypothesis on $f'$, the integral function $x \mapsto \int_0^x (x-t)f'(t) \text{d}t$ does not even have meaning in general.

Comment: You are correct but I don't know what you are trying to achieve. This is Facebook and not a rigorous textbook.

Comment: @vitamind Well, yes, I know... But Facebook or not, if it claims to be some piece of math, then it should be math, and not pseudo math. I was just trying to understand if my assessment of that is correct, and if so... how should this problem and its solution be patched/phrased to make it decent piece of math? That is the main point of my question.

Comment: I think it suffices for $f$ to be continuous at $1$ and to be integrable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think the problem is fine. The equation looks realistic, like the result of some science calculation. The question asks for a solution $f(1)$. Again this seems realistic. We may tacitly assume that $x$ is a real variable and that $f$ and its derivative are well defined. We can then start solving the problem. Finally we check the solution. It is unwise to question the validity of the problem by wondering about domain, differentiability and integrability.

Comment: @M.Wind I am not questioning the validity as a whole. I am just wondering under what conditions the solution is rigorous and valid. Obviously as stated it lacks some conditions.